# Arrows for variation tables

Tags: arrows

I want to create a variation table of function and I use arrows like these. Is there a way  to introduce the arrows? [image]

Comment: Adding an MWE will help others to help you. Please provide the minimal code which requires the feature you asked for. Also let us know what you have tried so far.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. That way the solution posted will be directly applicable to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen such arrows (and was not able to find them via [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)), so here is a `tikz` way to create them:

[image]

Depending on the actual application, there may be a better way to draw these.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\ArcDistance}{0.2cm}%
\newcommand{\BaseDist}{0.15cm}%
\newcommand{\RightUp}[1][]{\tikz[thick, baseline] 
    \draw [>->,#1]
        (0,0) -- ++(\BaseDist,0) to[out=0,in=-90] ++(\ArcDistance,\ArcDistance) -- ++(0,\BaseDist);%
}%

\newcommand{\UpRight}[1][]{\tikz[thick, baseline] 
    \draw [>->,#1]
        (0,0) -- ++(0,\BaseDist) to[out=90,in=180] ++(\ArcDistance,\ArcDistance) -- ++(\BaseDist,0);%
}%

\newcommand{\DownRight}[1][]{\tikz[thick, baseline] 
    \draw [>->,#1]
        (0,\ArcDistance+\BaseDist) -- ++(0,-\BaseDist) to[out=-90,in=180] ++(\ArcDistance,-\ArcDistance) -- ++(\BaseDist,0);%
}%

\newcommand{\RightDown}[1][]{\tikz[thick, baseline] 
    \draw [>->,#1]
        (0,\ArcDistance+\BaseDist) -- ++(\BaseDist,0) to[out=0,in=90] ++(\ArcDistance,-\ArcDistance) -- ++(0,-\BaseDist);%
}%



\begin{document}
\RightUp \quad \UpRight[red] \quad \DownRight[blue] \quad \RightDown[orange]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution with `xy`:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{xy} (-1,-1)="a",(2,2)="b" \ar@{>->}@/_3px/ "a";"b" \end{xy}}
\fbox{\begin{xy} (-1,-1)="a",(2,2)="b" \ar@{>->}@/^3px/ "a";"b" \end{xy}}   
\fbox{\begin{xy} (-1,2)="a",(2,-1)="b" \ar@{>->}@/_3px/ "a";"b" \end{xy}}
\fbox{\begin{xy} (-1,2)="a",(2,-1)="b" \ar@{>->}@/^3px/ "a";"b" \end{xy}}
\end{document}
```

[image]